# How can I pull a link out of a body of text in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube, split

I am creating a program that tells what time a Youtube video is linking to when given a link. I am already able to do what I want when I have only a link, but I want to know how to get the link if given a body of text.

For example if the input is:

```
"This is filler to test the program, https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=DkW5CSZ_VII#t=407 that is the link I want to pull out."
```

How can I simply get:

```
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=DkW5CSZ_VII#t=407"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
import re

s = "This is filler to test the program, https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=DkW5CSZ_VII#t=407 that is the link I want to pull out."

url = re.search("(http.+youtube\.com.+#t=\d+)", s).groups()[0]
```

But once you're using `re`, you can just go straight to extracting the time (moving the capture group to the `\d+` at the end, you can also ditch capturing the `http.+` at the start):

```
time = re.search("youtube\.com.+#t=(\d+)", s).groups[0]
```

Note that this regular expression won't play well with multiple links in the same block of text, which may be a problem. You can test regular expressions easily online using e.g. [`regex101`](http://regex101.com/#python).